# How to flag all answers of a particular user, or flag that user?

Tags: support, flags, advertising

I searched about database structure and documentation on Stack Overflow and I found a user who mentions a specific product in each of their answers (14 answers in total).

Are they advertising their product? (I don't know whether that product is theirs or they are connected with it, but I feels like that.)

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: The course of action is already answered below; I just want to add that typically you want to flag *content*, not *users*, since users are potentially transient. That's why there is no "flag user" option.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Flag one of his answers, explaining the situation in the flag's reason.

You can even link to this meta post in there, so the moderator that looks at your flag can weigh in on the discussion here.

After some digging minor around, It appears that user is the "Product Manager" of that product. (Profile picture matches the product's team page's "Product manager")

That's clear advertising without disclosing affiliation.

As such, I've taken the liberty to flag one of his answers:

> This user is the "Product Manager" of the product he links to (http://theirsite.example/our-team). This is advertising without disclosure of affiliation. He has this link in *all* of his answers.

<sup>(Which has been marked as "helpful" by now)</sup>

Comment: Just to add it's very handy when you include in the message a clear description of the issue and any "leg work" done (including relevant links) (like the example above) - it makes the moderator's job a lot easier :p

Comment: @JonClements are his answers are removed ? when I check its 14 in total, now it's only 8.

Comment: It looks like only his answers without upvotes are removed.

Comment: @Cerbrus So if SE moderator remove his answers which contain upvotes. does it effect on other user's profile (Badge or point) who comment or upvote his answers ?

Comment: @ShivamPandya: I'm not sure. As far as I know, you can't lose badges. Oh, and most of the questions he's answered on, are closed now.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ok, thanks for your valuable comments and guidance. It helps me and others too, to do not make mistake like that.

Comment: @ShivamPandya The answers that could warrant spam flags are removed. The questions that were old "can you recommend me..." have been closed.

Comment: Quite impressed both that you (a) found the user, and (b) didn't disclose who it was. Nice job!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks. Finding the user wasn't that difficult, though. ;-)

Comment: I'm failing in my attempts :(

Comment: You can see edit histories, right?

Comment: @JonClements Last time I attempted to put loads of info in the custom-reason box, I ran out of characters very quickly.